# Flask-restless endpoints with user resolution and filtration

Tags: python, flask, flask-restless

How would correctly should look API that returns only objects belonging to the user who asks for them?

```
api/version/items/<items_id>
```

or

```
api/version/user/<user_id>/items/<items_id>
```

In the first case, the server queried the database with a user id, which it obtains from its authentication.

I don't know how to create both cases in Flask-restless. I think a preprocessor will be useful, where I could get user_id from authorization (JWT token), but I can't find a way to use it as search parameters for DB.

```
from flask_jwt import JWT, jwt_required, current_user
...
manager.create_api(Item,
               methods=['GET'],
               collection_name='items',
               url_prefix='/api',
               preprocessors=dict(GET_SINGLE=[api_auth],GET_MANY=[api_auth]))   


@jwt_required()
def api_auth(*args, **kwargs):
    user_id = current_user.id
    # some code with user id addition.
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor would be the place where you build a query object. I think the endpoint for items should look simply like:

```
api/version/items
```

but whithin the preprocessor you would build a query object that would be passed with the request:

```
GET api/version/items?q={"filters":[{"name":"userid","op":"eq","val":10}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an endpoint that refers directly to the resources that you are trying to query. For example:

```
api/version/items
```

You should define a `get_single` and `get_many` preprocessor separately. The `instance_id` for the single (integer) and the `result` argument (dictionary) for the multiple pre-processor should be used to define what is returned to the user.

From the [Flask-restless docs](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#request-preprocessors-and-postprocessors):

> Those preprocessors and postprocessors that accept dictionaries as
>   parameters can (and should) modify their arguments in-place. That
>   means the changes made to, for example, the result dictionary will be
>   seen by the Flask-Restless view functions and ultimately returned to
>   the client.

Therefore in your pre-processors, you could do something like the following to retrieve the items (defined in a relationship to the user) in your database:

```
@jwt_required()
def api_auth_get_many(instance_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = current_user.id

    if instance_id in User.query.get(user_id).items:
        pass
    else:
        instance_id = None    # Do not return the value if not permitted

@jwt_required()
def api_auth_get_many(result=None, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = current_user.id
    result = User.query.get(user_id).items   # Return all items allowed for user
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think your first method will be called "api_auth_get_single" and second method is postprocessor (not preprocessor), where the result variable have to be a JSON dictionary.